# ASPxUploadControl - get uploaded file on the server-side

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, devexpress

I am using several `ASPxUploadControl`s in my page. I am successfully getting the uploaded files using `FileUploadComplete` event's `e.UploadedFile` argument and saving them.

But I want to be able to access (and save) them after saving my main entity. The reason is that I need to save them in a folder the name of which will be my entity's ID.

Is there a way I can do something like `myUploadControl.TheFileItIsCarrying` where ever I want in my C# code?

I tried `myUploadControl.UploadedFiles[0]`, but it will return a file with no content.

P.S.1: I thought of saving them in a temporary folder and then moving to the right folder. But in that case, I will not know each file is whose if several clients upload simultaneously.

P.S.2: The scenario is like saving a number of `Party` entities along with scanned copies of their identity documents, Resumes, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are actually saving the uploaded file to the server, you can save the upload file first, then you should be able to do whatever you want with the file, I don't know if you are actually saving it or not but that may be the problem that is occurring.

```
 If FileUpload1.HasFile Then
        Try
            Dim realPhysicalPath As String = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~\Files\"), FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
            FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(realPhysicalPath)

            Label1.Text = "File name: " & _
               FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName & "<br>" & _
               "File Size: " & _
               FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength & " kb<br>" & _
               "Content type: " & _
               FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType
        Catch ex As Exception
            Label1.Text = "ERROR: " & ex.Message.ToString()
        End Try
    Else
        Label1.Text = "You have not specified a file."
    End If
```

Then you can pull that specific file from the server, my example is assigning all the saved uploaded files to a GridView

```
 Dim filePaths() As String = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Files/"))
        Dim files As List(Of ListItem) = New List(Of ListItem)
        For Each filePath As String In filePaths

            files.Add(New ListItem(Path.GetFileName(filePath)))
        Next
        Dim hplnk As New HyperLinkField()

        hplnk.DataTextField = "test"
        hplnk.Text = "test"
        hplnk.HeaderText = "yourHeaderTextValue"

        GridView1.DataSource = files



        GridView1.DataBind()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I think the description of my problem was vague, so rather than explaining it in this comment, I edited my question.

Comment: Do you need help trying to find the best method to save and retrieve all of this or do you just need help on how to retrieve all of your uploaded files. the bottom half of my answer above should allow you to retrieve all the files that are save on the server, you can do this anywhere in your code. If you are just trying to figure out how to separate all the files by username or a name, you could just use a textbox and assign that value to one of the uploaded files attributes when your saving it

Comment: I was thinking maybe the UploadControl has some property from which I can retrieve the file (like how I have `e.UploadedFile` in `FileUploadComplete`), and not retrieve from the server. But I guess that's not possible, and I have to do as you said: first save them somewhere and then retrieve when I need.

Comment: As far as I remember, I believe I had a similar problem when I was setting mine up and I couldn't seem to retrieve the value back. It may be possible to do it the way you are wanting but I just know that saving it first, then retrieving works. You may be able to continue to look for other solutions and add breaks in your code while debugging to see if you can get the file before saving.

Comment: As I said before, if you are wanting to save each file with the username, if you havent already gotten a solution to this you could just add a textbox where they enter their username  or name before they upload then you can attach this textbox.text to the upload file or even create and save the upload file to a folder that you set the name to textbox.text. That way you could skip the step of retrieving the file and re-saving

Comment: Yes I am thinking of doing something like that. I was avoiding this in the first place to minimize mistakes, duplication, etc, and to always use unique PartyID instead of name, etc. (I am not creating `user` when clients submit, so I can't use the unique `username`. I will just create a `Party` entity which may become a user in future.) 
Thanks a lot for your help.